# filtered array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I want to display a message if a filtered array length === 0

```
users.filter((user) => {
    return user.name.includes('john')
}).map((user, index) => {
    console.log(user)   
})
```

i´m not sure where to put it. could it be inside the map? what´s the correct way?

Comment: Why not `const johns = users.filter(...); if (!johns.length) { /* display the message */}` or if dont need the filtered array you could use `const johnExists = users.some(,,,)`

Comment: The code you've provided contains syntax errors. `(user.name.includes('john')` is a bracket mismatch.

Comment: corrected. thanks @Olian04

Answer (score 4):

You can assign this method to a variable which will be a filtered array. And then check the length of that.

```
Let filteredArrayLength = users.filter((user) => {
    return (user.name.includes('john')
}). length;
```

After this you can put a conditional statement with value check of variable,

```
if(filteredArrayLength === 0){
   console.log("print something");
}
```

You can use .map only if you want to perform some operation on each of the filtered user object. Like if you want to fetch full name of the user, you can do a string concatenation of first and last name using map which will return a object with full name, it will return a array of same length with modified values.
Check this for example:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Comment: I see. but to iterate the filtered array you suggest to not use map() ?

Comment: I thought iteration was not in the picture, If you want iterate through the filtered array. Simply assign the iterated array to a variable which goes like let x = users.filter((user) => {
    return user.name.includes('john')
}).map((user, index) => {
    console.log(user)   
}). Now you can check the length of x as well as you can perform other operations on the object, map always returns a array of same length so no worries.

Comment: @AmitPandey thats what i have in my sample. I agree with your answer though

Answer (score 1):

If `filter()` returns empty array the `map()` will just not run and will pass on the empty array also so use it on the result of the combination

```
const res = users.filter((user) => {
    return user.name.includes('john')
}).map((user, index) => {
    console.log(user)  
    // need to return something or this map is pointless
})

console.log(res.length)
```

Comment: @charlietfl agree with you. but best practice would be to store the result and then operate on the filtered result set. Open for thoughts.

Comment: @Kamal why would that be best practice?

Comment: Why you want to do chaining... IMHO map chaining on this result doesn't serve any purpose according to me.

Comment: @Kamal am assuming OP wants to do a transformation of results from users array

Answer (score 1):

if the requirement is just know if their is any user name 'john', It could be done with ES6 `some` method;

```
if(!users.some(user=>user.name.includes('john'))){
     console.log('User John does not exist');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt

```
let users = [/*some array*/];
users = users.filter( user =>  user.name == 'john');

if( user.length > 0 ){
  //run code if the length is more than 0
  users = users.map((user, index) => { console.log(user)  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

under map is not the correct place becuase you are iterating through your filtered data.

you should store the filter resultset as follows:

```
    let users = users.filter((user) => {
                     return (user.name.includes('john'))
                });
     if(users.length > 0){
            //rest of the logic or iterate
     }else{
           // print or display your message
     }
```